# UIViewController subclass seems to load an unwanted nib

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nib

I have an `UIViewController` subclass that seems to load a Nib for its view resulting in a `NSUnknownKeyException`.

There is no explicit call to `init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)` or `loadNibNamed()` in my code.

And I don't get what is happening.

edit : here is the constructor I'm calling.

```
convenience init(overviewController:OverviewViewController) {
    self.init()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu)

Comment: did you set in your .xib file the correct viewcontroller name?

Comment: It should not load any nib.

Comment: Could you please also provide some code (when/how you call this viewcontroller) ?

Comment: see my update & also my self answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my `UIViewController` subclass was attempting to load a nib by itself based on its name !

I had a nib file that had the same name as my `UIViewController` subclass.

Just renaming the nib fixed my problem.